# Need to use created class to create an instance and use it in a Form.cs file

Tags: c#, forms, class, methods

So, I'm at a loss here. Have a small project to work on. Have to create a trip class then create a Windows Form app and use the class I created to use the form to calculate miles per gallons used and Cost Per Mile.

Have completed the class:

```
namespace TripCalculator
{
class Trip
{
    //Data members of class
    private string destination;
    private double distTrav;
    private double totalCostGas;
    private double numGallonsGas;


    //Default Constructor
    public Trip()
    {
    }

    //Constructor with all parameters
    public Trip(string tripDest, double milesTrav, double ttlPriceGas, n    double numGalls)
    {
        destination = tripDest;
        distTrav = milesTrav;
        totalCostGas = ttlPriceGas;
        numGallonsGas = numGalls;

    }

    //Propery for destination data field
    public string Destination
    {
        set
        {
            destination = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return destination;
        }


    }

    public double DistTrav
    {

        set
        {
            distTrav = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return distTrav;
        }
    }

    public double TotalCostGas
    {

        set
        {
            totalCostGas = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return totalCostGas;
        }
    }

    public double NumGallonsGas
    {

        set
        {
            numGallonsGas = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return numGallonsGas;
        }
    }

    public double CalculateMPG()
    {
         return (distTrav / numGallonsGas);
    }

    public double CalculateCPM()
    {
        return (totalCostGas / numGallonsGas);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return CalculateMPG().ToString();

    }

}
}
```

I want to be able to input destination, distance, cost, and gallons of gas into the form. Then I want the mpg and cost per mile to return to me in a textboxes.
Here's the form.cs

```
namespace TripCalculator
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void calcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string destination;
        double distTrav;
        double totalCostGas;
        double numGallonsGas;

        destBox.Focus();
        distBox.Focus();
        gasBox.Focus();
        galBox.Focus();

        Trip aTrip = new Trip (destination, distTrav, totalCostGas, numGallonsGas );

        mpgTxt.Text = aTrip.CalculateMPG().ToString();
        cpmTxt.Text = aTrip.CalculateCPM().ToString();
        destBox.Enabled = false;


    }
}
}
```

Im getting 4 errors saying "Use of unassigned local variable 'destination' (As well as for the other 3 variables above). It'll start the program, but returns nothing when I type in the text boxes and click the button. What am I doing wrong? Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void calcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string destination; // Give value for these
    double distTrav; // Give value for these
    double totalCostGas; // Give value for these
    double numGallonsGas; // Give value for these
}
```

Assign some value, either from user input or hard coded value for testing

Something like the code below, where you get the values from the text box in your Winform assuming you have such text boxes.

```
string destination = DestinationTextBox.Text;
double distTrav = double.Parse(DistTravTextBox.Text);
double totalCostGas = double.Parse(TotalCostGasTextBox.Text);
double numGallonsGas = double.Parse(NumGallonsGasTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: assigning text value to a double?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It worked! Crazy how creating these problems, you slip up like that. I'm very appreciative!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the textbox values for the variables

```
        string destination = txtDestination.Text;
        double distTrav = double.Parse(txtTrav.Text);
        double totalCostGas = double.Parse(txtCostGas.Text);
        double numGallonsGas = double.Parse(GallonsGas.Text);
```